# Google Colab Widgets

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have been using ipywidgets in google colab for a while but it today it started asking me to enable third party widgets and presented codes for custome widget managers. The widgets arent getting displayed any more. Was it because of an google colab update or am I making an error. I have attached a picture.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been detected by google colab team, [downgrading ipywidgets to 7.1.1 is the easiest way to solve the problem now.](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3020)